# InApp purchase incomplete payment

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have made a demo of IAP and in that I have registered my demo App in the apple account, I also have added the products info , description, app-id, title, priceTier, sandbox account for testing the payment process as described in the demo. I am facing two problems right now:-

a) Like for the very first time the popUp will ask for apple-id/password and I have provided both the values. It will show whether I want to confirm my payment and in that popup it will display the product name and price of the product. After clicking OK I am just getting nothing not even a mail from Apple, so how can I justify whether I have done a successful payment.

b) I also want to change my login id while buying the product. But every time it is by default taking my previous id and show me the password box only to enter the password. How can I reset this settings? Like I have tried reseting the simulator and again adding a new product in the my apple a/c in iTunes. So if any one got any idea please free to help. sharing my code below:-

```
    -(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
        {
            SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                          initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                          [NSSet setWithObject:kTutorialPointProductID]];
            request.delegate = self;

            [request start];
        }
        else

            NSLog(@"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings") ;
    }

    -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
    {

        NSArray *products = response.products;
            if (products.count != 0)
        {
            _product = products[0];
            NSLog(@"procudt info is %@",_product.localizedTitle);

    //        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
    //        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
    //        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
            [self purchaseProducts];
        } else {
            //_productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
        }

        products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

        for (SKProduct *product in products)
        {
            NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
        }
    }
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
               [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                 NSLog(@"Transaction complete");
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

First of all I am just fetching my product using my product id and I am getting response in the delegate method and if count >0 then "purchaseProducts" method will be called. But the thing is that my delegate method is not getting called, nothing is happening after I click on "OK" to buy the product. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Follow the given steps, hope it works-

First check if the user can make payments or not-

```
-(void)checkForPayement{

//First check if user can make payments
if (![SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
    // Show the error that user can't make payments.
}else{
    // Make the product request on App Store
    SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:IAP_PRODUCT_ID]];   // IAP_PRODUCT_ID is the product id which you got when you register the in-app-purchase
    productRequest.delegate = self;
    [productRequest start];
  }
}
```

If the product is available the you will get response in the following method-

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
if (response.products.count > 0) {
    SKProduct *validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    [self purchase:validProduct];
} else {
    // Product is not available so please cross check about the IAP_PRODUCT_ID
  }
}
```

If the request is failed, you will get callback in following method-

```
-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{  
    // Check here for the error
 }
```

Start your purchase

```
- (void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

}

You will get callback in given method and you can check the status of the transaction-

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            DDLogVerbose(@"Purchasing");
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                // User has cancelled the transaction
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

            DDLogVerbose(@"Restored");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        {
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
           //  Payment has been done and you should provide the purchased content or you may verify the receipt also
            DDLogVerbose(@"Purchased");

        }
            break;

        default:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

If you want more security then you can also [Verify receipt from app store](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)

**Solution of your problems**

a. While testing the in-app-purchase in sandbox environment, you will not get any mail for payment confirmation, you can check status of your payment in Storekit updatedTransactions delegate method. And no balance will be deducted in Sandbox environment.After entering the sandbox account details, also check the iTunes account if you can login or not? If not, you id may not verified so verify your id.

b. Before trying in-app-purchase just logout the apple id from Settings -> iTunes & App Store. Tap on the apple id and click on logout. And when you initiate in-app-purchase enter the sandbox account credentials and don't login the sandbox account in actual production environment because it may invalidate your sandbox account.

Comment: thanks for very nice explanation and because of this I have accepted your answer. Actually before this I worked on another payment gateway and in sandbox Env I was getting a test email after the payment. The name of the payment gateway is Telr Payment Gateway. Pooja rocks.